# mysql: обновление бд путем наката миграций

Tags: mysql, база-данных, миграция

На сервере крутится БД [mysql] - появились новые файлы с миграциями, порядка нескольких десятков. Вопрос: можно ли с помощью какого-то скрипта для mysql или mysqldump (возможно как-то с помощью workbench) накатить все эти миграции на базу, чтобы не выполнять их по одиночке ?)

Comment: А что такое "файлы миграции", что в них ? Если sql - то скармливайте его просто команде mysql. А если не sql - то тем средством которым вы их готовили

Comment: mysql - скрипты с содержимым вроде создать таблицу N, в таблице M добавить поле и т.д.

Comment: Если под unix, то простейший скрипт вроде `cat *.sql | mysql -u пользователь -pпароль имя-базы` маску `*.sql` только сделать такой что бы захватила все нужные файлы

Comment: к сожалению, 'окна' ) но мысль понял, спасибо) а что касается workbench'а - умеет ли он делать подобные вещи, не подскажите ?

Comment: На счет него не знаю, он вроде просто графическая среда. зачем ему это. С другой стороны, у него в каталоге лежит mysql.exe, что то мне подсказывает, что он может в командной строке все выполнять, значит можно какой нибудь .bat сделать

Answer (score 1):

Если кому-то пригодится. Скрипт на python:

```
import os
current_directory = "ваш_путь_к_файлам"
# чтобы mysql работала с консоли, добавьте
# путь к mysql_folder в path
for filename in os.listdir(current_directory):
    full_path = current_directory + filename
    query = "mysql -u username -puserpass dbname < " + full_path
    os.system(query);
```